# How to change a part of the src and push it into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.myshp_list_product_image img').each(function() {
    tn_array.push($(this).attr('src')); 
});
```

With this code I put my image src in an array.

Every image has a part that says "1s" like this: "this-is-my-image-1s.jpg"

I want to change the '1s' part to '2s' and after that push it to the array.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can use .replace in JS but that might be have bug in some  images name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method replace the `1s` with `2s` and although you can use  [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to generate the array.

```
var tn_array = $('.myshp_list_product_image img').map(function() {
   // return the updated attribute value
   return $(this).attr('src').replace('1s', '2s');
   // get the result as an array from jQuery object
}).get();
```

Comment: `return $(this).attr('src').replace(/1s/, '2s')`  does the first parameter in `replace()` needs to be included withing `slash '/' `

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 : that's for regex ,,, here it can be string since we just want to remove the first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

use replace

```
$('.myshp_list_product_image img').each(function() {
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   tn_array.push(src.replace("1s.jpg", "2s.jpg"));
});
```